# Need resource on how to write Cognos security provider

Tags: cognos

I need to write Cognos security provider.  However, I have no clue where to start from.

Is there any resources that can help me start.  Also do you know of any classes that teach about how to write Cognos security providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read chapter 3 of the "Cognos Authentication Provider Developer Guide" (file dg_auth.pdf which is included in your Cognos SDK product installation)
2. Look at the provided sample at *install_location*/sdk/java/AuthenticationProvider
3. In the Cognos Configuration application, add a new "namespace" resource of type 
   "Custom Java Provider" under "Local Configuration > Security > Authentication".